# MySQL Workbench 8.0.32.CE crashes on macOS Monterey 12.6.3

Tags: mysql-workbench

This happens to me when I run the `show databases` commands; and the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` command.
The other commands I can write and execute normally.
MacBook Pro early 2015, 64 bits.

I tried to check the MySQL version (x86_64 Homebrew install), I tried to restart the processes.

Comment: Would you consider using Skype Screen Share to show someone what you are seeing when this situation is a problem?  View profile for contact info.

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the similar problem with 8.0.32, but I tried with 8.0.30 and my problem got resolved. So you can try with lesser version 8.0.30 or equal.

Answer (score 2):

I was also having the same issue where if I ran any type of query the entire application would crash, v8.0.31 seems to be the most stable version and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The bug was fixed in version 8.0.33, but for now ,the homebrew repo is 8.0.32. I will install the package from mysql site manually.

Also, there is some discussion on [the Apple forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/724378?page=2) and [a bug issue was submitted to MySQL](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109671).

Comment: I just tried to install 8.0.33 on Monterey 12.6.5.  The MySQL download page says it's compatible with Monterey.  It installs without any problems, but when you start it, macOS says that it is only compatible with Ventura.